# Get data from a string/Json url

Tags: c#, json, geocoding

So I want to get the latitude and longitude (lat and lgn) in this URL which looks just like a Json file but whenever I try to use  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` I get an error...

Here is my code :

```
using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Boucle");
    WebClient n = new WebClient();
    var json = n.DownloadString(url);
    string valueOriginal = Convert.ToString(json);
    dynamic GPS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Geocoding>(json);
    Console.WriteLine($"{GPS.results}");
}
```

And here is my class :

```
public class Geocoding
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Result[] results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Address_Components[] address_components { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public  double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address_Components
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The Json file URL is like as below:

```
{
    "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "41",
               "short_name" : "41",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Boulevard Vauban",
               "short_name" : "Boulevard Vauban",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Lille",
               "short_name" : "Lille",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nord",
               "short_name" : "Nord",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hauts-de-France",
               "short_name" : "Hauts-de-France",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "59800",
               "short_name" : "59800",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "41 Boulevard Vauban, 59800 Lille, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.6341809,
               "lng" : 3.0487116
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.63552988029151,
                  "lng" : 3.050060580291502
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.63283191970851,
                  "lng" : 3.047362619708498
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJfZ8S2njVwkcRmcb0tz_XNNE",
         "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest", "university" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I get the error : "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : ''GeocodingApi.Geocoding' doesn't have definition for 'results''". I tried everything from removing the `<Geocoding>` to keeping it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to deserialise to a nested class. You can either remove the outer class and use the `Rootobject` class directly or deserialise with the full namespace:

```
Geocoding.Rootobject GPS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Geocoding.Rootobject>(json);
```

Note the variable is of the same type and not `dynamic`, there's very rarely a good use case to not use the correct types.

Comment: So, I tried changing it and now (thanks to you) I don't get an error but I just get `GeocodingApi.Geocoding+Result[]` on the console when I try `Console.WriteLine($"{GPS.results}")`

Comment: That's because the `$"{GPS.results}"` string interpolation is printing out your type. If you want to know each individual value you will need to loop through that array.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was so disappointed when it read that that I didn't think straight !

Answer (score 1):

Remove the RootObject class definition and collapse its members into Geocoding.  Your class structure does not match the JSON file.  Alternatively you can Deserialize the string as a "RootObject" rather than a "Geocoding"